# Calculate the eigenvalues of the following 3x3 matrix and solving a cubic with complex roots?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, cubics

I have a question regarding a 3x3 matrix and its eigenvalues. The matrix is
$A= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 2\\-2 & -1 & 2 \\ -1 & -2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

What I have attempted is to let $det(A-\lambda I)=0$, which resulted in the cubic,
$-\lambda ^3+3\lambda ^2 -7\lambda +11 =0$

I believe I have worked out the correct polynomial, but without the help of a computer or the equation for cubic roots I am unsure on how to solve this equation. Normally my method would involve guessing a solution (a factor of $\lambda^0$, in this case 11) and then doing polynomial division. In this case the polynomial has one real root and a complex conjugate.

Comment: Not much you can do here: your cubic is fine. Just use Cardano's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Comment: There's no general method, to solve a cubic.  You've to ultimately get creative in coming up with solutions. This'll help even when you try to solve differential equations.

Comment: @Iota I disagree with your statement. There *is* a general formula (Cardano's formula, lined above), as much as there is a quadratic formula to solve a quadratic equation. It is just more tedious and cumbersome for a cubic than it is for a quadratic equation, but the roots of a cubic can always be found algebraically. In some cases, you can be 'creative' and find shortcuts, but this is by no means the *only* way to find the full set of roots.

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo Sorry, I didn't know the formula. But I still think being creative at finding solutions is a much more deep learning than any formula to find zeroes.